# How to give file URL hosted in s3 as a document remoteUrl for Dousign remote signing API?

Tags: docusignapi

Im trying to give my s3 file's url as a document remoteUrl in remote signing API. As it becomes easy to do this way, instead of downloading the file to my server and then pass on the doc to docusign API. When I made the bucket public, I was able to pass the object url as document remoteUrl and docusign was able to pick it up and send it for signature but my usecase is not a public bucket.

The s3 bucket only allows allowed domains, so I have added  "https://account-d.docusign.com/*" "https://account.docusign.com/*" as allowed domains but even then I am facing this issue :

```
ERROR {errorCode: 'INVALID_REQUEST_PARAMETER',message: "The request contained at least one invalid parameter. An error occurred while downloading the data for document with id=1. Please ensure that the 'remoteUrl' parameter is correct."}
```

Are the docusign allowed domains correct or am I missing something?

Comment: is this unauthenticated?? meaning anyone can go to this URL and get the document? 
I assume not, I assume you have some need to authenticate, not sure, but DocuSign doesn't have your AWS credentials, right?

Comment: It is unauthenticated but we restrict the access to the objects by granting access to only allowed domains. So if we add docusign's domain, can the docusign fetch the document ?. I have also added the basepath "https://demo.docusign.net/restapi" as allowed domain but still no use.

Comment: is there a way to use IP addresses? even that would be tricky, but the list of DocuSign IP addresses can be found here - https://www.docusign.com/trust/security/esignature

Answer (score 0):

OK, let's clear some confusion here.
First, [DocuSign support various public cloud](https://support.docusign.com/guides/ndse-user-guide-give-docusign-access-to-your-cloud-storage) providers for cloud storage where you can have the files stored that will be sent to DocuSign to be part of an envelope sent for signature.
That list doesn't include Amazon S3, it is focused on end-user/consumer cloud storage and requires that you connect your DocuSign account to the cloud provider for authentication.
So the `remoteURL` property is not relevant to your scenario.

You can build an integration that goes to S3 using AWS APIs, get the file and then send it to DocuSign from wherever your app is hosted (AWS would make it easy) and if you do that - there's nothing different about sending a file you obtained from Amazon S3 vs. a file that was stored on-prem.